# Remove selected value from list in shiny SelectInput

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have one input:

```
selectInput(
        "Linie_D",
        label = "Linie",
        choices = Liste_Linie_D,
        selected = "all" ,
        multiple = TRUE
      )
```

The default here is "all". If I now select another input, it will be appended to the list. My question: Is it possible to delete the default when entering a new value?
The deletion of "all" should be done when another value is entered.

Comment: I'd recommend checking out `shinyWidgets::pickerInput` you can have all values selected by default and provide an intuitive UI to deselect values. That way you can avoid having to manually include an "all" choice. Otherwise use `updateSelectInput`

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example. I do not understand what you mean by "default". And what exactly do you mean by 'The deletion of "all"'? Do you want to remove it from `choices` or from `selected`?

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this plugin to the selectInput:

```
selectInput(
        "Linie_D",
        label = "Linie",
        choices = Liste_Linie_D,
        selected = "all" ,
        multiple = TRUE,
        options = list('plugins' = list('remove_button'), 'create' = TRUE, 'persist' 
        = FALSE)
      )
```

I try this code:

```
 selectInput(
      "Gebäude_ZDIM_A",
      label = "Gebäude SAP",
      choices = Liste_Gebaeude_ZDIM_A,
      selected = "all" ,
      multiple = TRUE,
      options = list('plugins' = list('remove_button'), 'create' = TRUE, 'persist' 
                     = FALSE)
    )
```

and get the error:
Error in selectInput("Gebäude_ZDIM_A", label = "Gebäude SAP", choices = Liste_Gebaeude_ZDIM_A, : unused argument (options = list(plugins = list("remove_button"), create = TRUE, persist = FALSE))

What goes wrong?

Sorry, I think that you might need to load the `shinyjs` package for this to work correctly. I'm looking at code where I've used this before and I'm using `selectizeInput` instead of `selectInput`, so this option might not be available for `selectInput`. For more information, see [here](https://groups.google.com/g/shiny-discuss/c/cWMf8NWhT0M) and [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/selectize.html).

Also, since you're using `selected = "all"` and calling names from a data frame column, you might also have to modify your choices to be:

`choices = c("all", unique(df$Liste_Gebaeude_ZDIM_A)`

Where the unique function pulls all of the different names from the data frame column called Liste_Gebaeude_ZDIM_A. Hopefully this helps!